# Entity Framework stored procedure handling unassigned values

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns user Token if authentication passes like this

```
BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF --Tricky Part
DECLARE @token uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @user_id as int
SET @user_id = (SELECT UserID  FROM Users
WHERE @email = Email AND @password = PasswordKey)
IF @user_id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @token = NEWID()
    UPDATE Users SET Token = @token
    WHERE UserID = @user_id
    SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @user_id
END
END
```

Without `SET FMTONLY OFF` it returns Token BUT only if user entered correct cardinalities else error

> *A member of the type, 'Token', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.*

occurs.

Now I have another stored procedure (almost same as this one) which returns single `Product` determined by ID which I pass to the stored procedure and it works fine even when I send non-existing ones. In function import, one stored procedure shows me columns which returns and another one doesn't. For clarity here are two images which shows stored procedures and function import [Images](http://imgur.com/a/4jT8M#0)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = @user_id
```

List out the names of the columns that you wish to return from the Users table instead of just using SELECT *.

```
SELECT ColumnName,
       AnotherColumn,
       YouGetThePoint
FROM  ...
```

It sounds like the DataReader is being populated with column names that are different than the expected column names.  Have you stepped through with a debugger and/or listed out the actual column names that are being returned from the procedures to is if they are just being given arbitrary names (e.g. T1, T2).

Comment: if u looking at the images u see he uses `select token from ...`

Comment: I have tried both scenarios, but neither of them does not work. I can see (e.g. 5 items) that stored procedure returns in debugger but without any column name